# How do I get the name of the SQL server in Azure in Azure logs?

Tags: kql, azure-monitor

I am using KQL to populate grafana queries.
Once of the things I am missing is the server name of a PaaS DB.
I have the following query, but do not know how to add in the server name.

I have tried using `ServerName` but that fails, that only seems to work in summary queries.

```
resources
| project name, type, resourceGroup
| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
| where name != 'master'
```

If I get all the fields in the data, I can see the full `id` which includes the server, but I can't see a way to reduce down to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I wanted!

```
resources
| where type =~ "microsoft.sql/servers/databases"
| extend serverName = tostring(split(id, "/", 8)[0])
| project name, resourceGroup, serverName
```

Comment: To get just the server names:

    resources
    | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Sql/servers'
    | project id, name